# Save changed Width of a TableView Column Java

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

sorry for the title, i could not find a better title name for my problem.

To quickly explain my problem/question:

[image: See Columns]

It is possible to change the width of a column by dragging it left or right. 
Now I want to know how does the program detect that the width has been changed?
In SceneBuilder, there is "On Edit Start", "On Edit Commit" and "On Edit Cancel" for each TableColumn Item.

[image: See here.]

After the detection has been done, I want to automatically change the PrefWidth of that column like this.

```
tableColumnID.setPrefWidth(tableColumnId.getWidth);
```

tableColumnID.getWidth is in this case the changed width after increasing/decreasing the width of a column manually with the mouse.

Comment: It is possible to embedd images in your post, it may make it easier if you did that. It is usually good practice to do so

Comment: @Dylan I believe doing so requires a certain amount of reputation (don't know how much).

Comment: @O.Conor Listen to the [`TableColumnBase.width`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#widthProperty) property. You can add a delay so that if the property is changed, but hasn't been changed in the last second or so, then do something.

Comment: I tried to embedd it, but that was not possible.
 Unfortunately, i have no clue what is meant with listening to that property.